# Date conversion in Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a date in Pyspark dataframe in "String" format as "dd-MMM-yyyy ( eg "01-Jan-2022").
I want to convert this to date with the same format so the Output should be

```
01-Jan-2022
```

The code i am using for this is as below, but the format doesn't convert properly. It converts the date to "dd-MM-yyyy" format (ie 01-01-2022), whereas i want it in "dd-MMM-yyyy"(ie "01-Jan-2022") format.

My code is here:

```
df = df.withColumn("mydate",F.to_date(df.mydate,"dd-MMM-yyyy"))
```

This results in date type converted to "date" from "string" but the format doesn't convert properly.

Comment: What do you mean by "format doesn't convert properly"? If you are taking about the output you see after `df.show()`, then that is just the default toString output of data type.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of [`to_date`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_date.html) links to the format definition [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html).

Have you tried using `dd-LLL-yyyy`?

Answer (score 0):

Assume your original data has date as string:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["01-Jan-2022",],["31-Dec-2022",]], schema=["date_initial"])
df.show()

+------------+
|date_initial|
+------------+
| 01-Jan-2022|
| 31-Dec-2022|
+------------+
```

Parse this string date to Date type. The "yyyy-MM-dd" output here is just the toString  representation of the Date type. You can find the implementation details in this [source code link](https://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/datetime/datetime.py). Look for `__repr__` method in class `date`.

```py
df = df.withColumn("date_dt", F.to_date("date_initial", format="dd-MMM-yyyy"))
df.show()

+------------+----------+
|date_initial|   date_dt|
+------------+----------+
| 01-Jan-2022|2022-01-01|
| 31-Dec-2022|2022-12-31|
+------------+----------+
```

You can format the Date type back to string to confirm:

```py
df = df.withColumn("date_str", F.date_format("date_dt", format="dd-MMM-yyyy"))
df.show()

+------------+----------+-----------+
|date_initial|   date_dt|   date_str|
+------------+----------+-----------+
| 01-Jan-2022|2022-01-01|01-Jan-2022|
| 31-Dec-2022|2022-12-31|31-Dec-2022|
+------------+----------+-----------+
```